# EGit does not commit

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I had a Scala project, synchronized with GitHub. Then I had to reinstall my OS. I installed Eclipse and EGit, then imported the project from the remote location.

Now, when I make changes to the project, commit does nothing. It does not open the dialog which lets me enter a message and select files to commit. The files are still displayed as changed in the package explorer. I read somewhere that EGit logs errors to stdout, but when I start Eclipse from the command line, I see no errors logged.

If I try to push, I get asked for the passphrase for my ssh keys, and there is a window with a progress bar, but then the content of the remote repository does not change.

I am quite new to Git and don't know where to go further to diagnose the problem. What I did was to get into the Eclipse preferences and restore the defaults on preferences windows in the Git group. This didn't help.

One thing which I noticed is that the project itself is in the `git` directory, so when I make changes to the code and save, they get written there, not under the `workspace` directory of Eclipse. I don't know if this is relevant (maybe it can't write the changes to the local repository because there is no local repository copy to be updated?), but I didn't see a setting to change this location when I imported the project.

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?